# Automation studio behaviour on months that don't have a 29th day

Tags: automationstudio

I've got a specific use case where we need to send emails out on the 29th of every month.

I'm using a scheduled Automation Studio SQL to kick off a journey on the 29th of each month. However, I'm unsure how this would behave during February in a non-leap year.

Will it run on the 1st of March or not at all?

Comment: You should have asked this question yesterday :-) But my assumption will be that the automation will not run in February on non-leap years.

Comment: It will behave the same way as automations scheduled on 31st in months that only have 30 days - like Lukas said, it will not run at all

Comment: Haha, yeah. Busy having to send something now because of it. Thanks